# changing label text of form from another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Good day, 
I have a couple of methods that take long in my forms code. I would like to display a message (using a `label` on another form) to inform the user about what is going on, so they don't assume program is unresponsive.

I don't want to use `MessageBox.Show()`, because I would like to have an object that I can change the text of, and dispose when needed, without user being able to close it.

so far I have somthing like this: in my main form:

```
private void Foo()
{
    Form2 infoPopup = new Form2();
    infoPopup.setText("running function1");
    infoPopup.Show();
    slowFunction1();
    infoPopup.setText("running function2");
    slowFunction2();
    infoPopup.Dispose();
}
```

as you might guess, in Form 2 I have a function like this:

```
private void setText(string message)
{
   this.label1.Text=message;
}
```

Unfortunately this solution only partially works. I do get the `form2` popup message but the content of the label in `form2` do not change.

Thanks

Comment: Try calling `label1.Refresh ();` in your method that updates the text.

Comment: clear concise answer. solved the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application is busy, redrawing controls is not a priority. So unless your code is running in a worker thread, the UI won't update reliable.

You can force an update though. Controls and forms all have a `Update()` method. It forces the object to redraw itself.

Depending on your particular case, you might also want to research the `Invalidate()` and `Refresh()` methods.